# Python logging in GCP kubernetes

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, python-logging

I have a dockerized a python application. I want to deploy the container on GCP Kubernetes. I have included logs in the application by using the `logging` module. 
My question is does by default the logs will be stored to `stackdriver` or should I need to use `google.cloud.logging` integrated with `logging` module to store the logs to the `stackdriver`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python) on how to make Py and Stackdriver work.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.